# Turn my span value into a input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, html

I have some (javascript) values I want to submit via a form. One of these values I get using a span:

```
<span id="score_win" style="color:#ffbe5e;">0</span>
```

This wont submit in a form. So I though, let's convert the javascript output to get it into my input field. I thought this up for the input field:

```
<input type="text" id="score_win" name="Score" value="0" style="text-align: left; background:transparent; border-style: none; color:#ffbe5e; margin: 0px; font: 14px Arial; width:40px;" readonly />
```

So far so good, only the value doesn't show now. This is because I haven't edited the javascript part yet. Problem is: how do I do that correctly so that this value can be used in my input field? Since my own attempts failed, I thought asking you guys.

The javascript part:

```
function foundMatchingBlocks(event, params) {
      params.elements.remove();
      //score += 100;
      score += pointsAvailable;
      $('#score').text(score);
      $('#status2').html('+' + pointsAvailable);
      pointsAvailable = 100;
      $('#score_win').text(score);
};
```

Kind regards,
Maurice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set the value of an input field:

```
$('#score_win').val('100');
```